# Запуск файла в android приложении

Tags: android

Нужно из android приложения запустить бинарный файл. Какие права нужно выдать и какой командой запускать? Пишу на Java. Телефон без root. Пишет permission denied. Пробовал поменять права через adb - не получилось. Также пробовал копировать файл в разные места - тот же результат, хотя флаг 'x' был выставлен.

Comment: покажите код как запускаете бинарник

Comment: `p=new ProcessBuilder().command("/mnt/sdcard/stockfish.android.armv8").start();`

Comment: пишет permission denied

Comment: по этому пути `"/mnt/sdcard/stockfish.android.armv8"` флаг 'x' не горит, а вот по этому `"/storage/stockfish.android.armv8"`, в андроид студии горит, а в adb, знаки вопроса. Но все равно не запускается.

Comment: сделал, что и в adb горят иксы, далее запускаю прямо из adb - тот же результат.